# Linux group folder permissions

Tags: linux, file-permissions

I am using Redhat/Centos 7.

Currently I have a local directory called /lcldisk, the users login in with a network account, which means when they make a directory under /lcldisk it is owned by the user and their domain group, so their department. Department groups don't provide permissions to any groups for this directory.

I am trying to make a local group, throw 3 users into it, make the group own everything ( every file and folder including /lcldisk). I also want every new file and folder to be owned by this group with directory=rwx and file=rw

```
mkdir /lcldisk
chmod 777 /lcldisk
```

**user**

```
cd /lcldisk
mkdir johnnydepp
```

users have created folder and files, most of it looks like.

Years later, they are wanting a couple of users to be able to access the data under /lcldisk for no matter which user, just in case they leave or something.

```
groupadd ns_admGrp
usermod -a -G ns_admGrp bettywhite

chown -R :ns_admGrp /lcldisk
cd /lcldisk

chmod g+rwx /lcldisk/
find . -type d -exec chmod g+rwx {} \;
find . -type f -exec chmod g+rw {} \;
```

Now how to keep all files and folders for every user, and every directory no matter how deep owned by the user and this group with those permissions?

I know sticky bit when set keeps the group, I still need the folder and file permissions.

What parts to this puzzle am I obviously missing? Do I need to look into acl's, umask, something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For most filesystems that use POSIX ACLs, set a "default" ACL with a group entry on the directory and all subdirectories:

```
setfacl -R -m d:g::rwx /mydir
```

This applies to the assigned group that files inherit thanks to the setgid bit. For a custom group you can of course use `[d:]g:mygroup:rwx`.

When newly created files inherit this ACL they'll automatically gain a `mask::rw` entry, masking out the unnecessary +x bit. Newly created subdirectories will get the whole +rwx.

There's no automatic way to apply default ACLs to existing items (no real inheritance like in NTFS).

Answer (score 0):

You're better off using ACL's.

In your case, what you want to do is run:

```
setfacl -m g:ns_admGrp:rwx -R /lcldisk
setfacl -m d:ns_admGrp:rwx -R /lcldisk
```

The first command will set the group permissions for the directory/files, and the second command will set the default permissions for the directory/files.

This page expands more on the topic - https://linuxman.co/linux-server/how-to-use-acl-in-linux/